# Xor not working with VisuabBasic as expected

Tags: vb.net, xor

This is a simple program using which I am trying to demonstrate the working of some basic crypto. algorithms with VB but this piece of code below just does not work as expected.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RichTextBox2.Text = ""
        Dim text, key As String
        text = RichTextBox1.Text
        key = TextBox1.Text
        Dim i = 0
        For i = 0 To text.Length - 1 Step 1
            RichTextBox2.Text = Chr(Asc(text(i)) Xor Asc(key(i Mod key.Length))) + RichTextBox2.Text
        Next
    End Sub
```

I am getting some crappy output as my cipher text and when I try to get the original text It only gives me garbage

```
Output:

        E
    O
    LO

Input:
 text: this is a sample text
 key : pass
```

Comment: One thing comes to mind.  In your For loop, your pre-pending each step to the previous, instead of appending it.  Not sure if this was intended , but it seems odd.  Another thing to keep in mind when using a string to hold encoded text.  If an individual character code isn't printable it'll get changed to null and your result won't decode.  You'll probably be better off using a byte array.

Comment: Well I had no luck with appending either. But if xor'ing two chars if the value is greater than 128 wont vb.net round it with 128, I mean if I `ascii('a') xor ascii('z')`the result will be `27` instead of some null (caused by any out of range probs.). Well, that is how python2.7 behaves and I am able to run the above code there without any probs !!!

Comment: It's not really about the return value it's about how .net displays strings.  They had to have some way of interpreting unprintable characters and they chose to use null character.  That's why using a byte array will give you truer results.

Comment: @tinstaafl Hmm, that is a nice suggestion, I will keep in mind, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are using for encryption/decryption is wrong because comes from a wrong assumption: the length of the encrypted and unencrypted strings have to be identical (what is rarely the case).

The basic encrytion/decryption for what you aim is:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1
    RichTextBox2.Text = Chr(Asc(text(i)) Xor key) & RichTextBox2.Text
Next
```

Where `key` is an integer.

What you have done is changing the `key` part such that strings might be accounted for. The problem is that the way you have chosen to accomplish this aim does not deliver the same key for both situations (encryption/decryption): you are generating your key as a function of the given length being considered (encrypted string vs. decrypted string) and thus you assume that both lengths are identical what is not the case.

------------------------ UPDATE (sample code with key as integer)

Add 2 buttons (`ButtonEncrypt` and `ButtonDecrypt`) and two textboxes (`TextBoxInput` and `TextBoxOutput`) to your form and copy this code:

```
Private Sub ButtonEncrypt_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonEncrypt.Click

    TextBoxOutput.Text = ""
    Dim key As Integer = 123
    Dim inputText As String = TextBoxInput.Text
    For i As Integer = 0 To inputText.Length - 1
        TextBoxOutput.Text = Chr(Asc(inputText(i)) Xor key) & TextBoxOutput.Text
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonDecrypt_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonDecrypt.Click

    TextBoxOutput.Text = ""
    Dim key As Integer = 123
    Dim inputText As String = TextBoxInput.Text
    For i As Integer = 0 To inputText.Length - 1
        TextBoxOutput.Text = Chr(Asc(inputText(i)) Xor key) & TextBoxOutput.Text
    Next

End Sub
```

For example, if you input "encrypt this string" in `TextBoxInput` and click on `ButtonEncrypt`, you would get "encrypted string" (I cannot copy what I get here because the characters are not recognised) in `TextBoxOutput`. If now you copy this "encrypted string" into `TextBoxInput` and click on `ButtonDecrypt` you would see that "encrypt this string" would appear in the `TextBoxInput`. That is, you can use this code to encrypt/decrypt anything.

The diffence between this code and your code is that the `key` I am using is common for both cases (encrypt and decrypt). The one you use is not constant because you define it as a function of the length of the given string (decrypted or encrypted one). Thus the solution for your problem is making sure that the `key` you use is the same in both cases.

Finally, I want to re-insist in the fact that this algorithm is expecting the `key` to be an integer (because `Chr` can only deal with integers); but there is an easy workaround (what you did): relying on a key defined as a string and, while performing the encryption/decryption, convert the given character into an integer (by relying on `Asc`). Thus your (general) approach to the problem is right with the only problem that the way you used to account for the different characters of the `key` is wrong: it relies on the length of the given string which differs from the encrypted/decrypted version and thus provokes accounting for different keys; that is, considering the key 123 to encrypt and 513 to decrypt (dumb example).

I hope that my point is clearer now.

Comment: I wish to have `key` with key length longer than just one integer, But your algo. does not seem to do it ..

Comment: No, you don't get my point. The algorithm I wrote is the basic approach for the encrypting/decrypting using the Xor you intend. The idea is having a key which is a (low enough) integer. If you test this algorithm, with, for example, 123 as key. It will work for both encrypting and decrypting. If you want to move from this (key as a small enough integer) to key as a string you should make sure that it gets always the same definition. For example: accounting for the characters of key. Give me some minutes and I will write a code to explain the point better.

Comment: I'm in no hurry, eagerly waiting for your improved algo

Comment: There you have it. No, it is not an improved algo and, actually, this is not even my algo. This is the standard algo for this situation. I have written a more detailed code to explain my point properly (but the algo is exactly the same). If you have still doubts, please let me know.

Comment: k I understand that I need to use the same key, but I don seem to get it. From what I see you are xor'ing each and every char from the input string with ONE single int key for all the chars. Is it possible to have, like for sample text ABC would be encrypted with (A xor k1 , B xor k2 , C xor k3) where (k1,k2,k3) is the key supplied ... so on , instead of working like (A xor k, B xor k, C xor k) where (k) is the key supplied, which I assume your algo does.

Comment: The usual aproach to the problem is relying on one key (this is a pretty simplistic/standarised encryption/decryption); but you can do tests and bring this approach to its limits. What you have to make sure is that you will be considering exactly the same key(s) for decrytion and encryption.

Comment: Understand what is being done: this algorithm converts each character into a position in an array (Chr/Asc) and encrypts them by moving the positions X places. For example, imagine the array : temp(0)=a, temp(1)=b, temp(2)=c and temp(3)=d; this algorithm is the same than saying: consider all the characters in the array temp moved 2 positions; it would convert a into c, b into d, etc. What you cannot do is moving a random number of positions to encrypt and decrypt (what your approach was doing). But you can move the first letter 1 position, the second one 2 positions... (as complex as you wish)